# Using Apps Script to import a CSV file to sheets results not importing all data

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm importing CSV data from a file in Google Drive using this function:

```
function importList(fileId, sheetName) {
  let stringified = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  let newData = Utilities.parseCsv(stringified);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sht = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sht.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

The function runs without errors. The problem is that the CSV has around 500+rows and 10 columns and the imported result brings in only the first 302 rows.  The data 'stops' in one case at 337 rows and 5 columns.  Where the CSV has a blank cell at the 6th column of row 337, this is where the data appears to stop importing.  A similar result occurs where I import some other files, but the results are not consistent.

When I Logger.log the length of newData array, this is reflecting the length of the array being sent to the sheet and a Logger.log of the last row of the array also returns what is being posted to the sheet.

It's like the getBlob() isn't getting all of the data in the CSV file. I've not been able to find similar issues encountered by others.  Is there some other method I can use to return a more reliable result?  Or am I doing something wrong in my approach?

### EDIT

The CSV files are only about 66KB in size, so they are small.
As the files contain sensitive data, I have recreated one that still gives me a similar result. The randomised file has 1000 rows in the CSV file and import is stopping at row 305.  A copy of the randomised CSV file is here:
[TestCSVImport](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J_QcYW_YbifChADqr9oyOmH4dBSTlljf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: inconsistencies in data are very common

Comment: Does the CSV file you are trying to parse contain sensitive info? Can you share it?

Comment: What is the size of your CSV file?